# Since modern computer uses virtual memory, why do we still encounter "out of memory" issue?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I am learning the concept of virtual memory, but this question has been confusing me for a while. Since most modern computers use virtual memory, when a program is in execution, the os is supposed to page data in and out between RAM and disk. But why do we still encounter "out of memory" issue? Could you please correct me if I misunderstood the concept? I really appreciate your explanation.

PS: For example, I was analyzing a large amount of data (>100G) output from simulation on a computing cluster, and read in the data to an C array. Very often the system crashed and complained a memory error.

Answer (score 0):

First: Modern computer do indeed use virtual memory, however there is no magic here. Memory is not created out of nothing. Virtual memory schemes typically allow a portion of the mass storage sub-system (aka hard disk) to be used to hold portions of the process that are (hopefully) less frequently used.

This technique allows processes to use more memory than is available as RAM. However nothing is infinite. Eventually all RAM and Hard Drive resources will be used up and the process will get an out of memory error.

Second: It is not unheard of for operating systems to place a cap on the memory that a process may use. Hit that cap and again, the process gets an out of memory error.

Comment: Even with infinite disk space and RAM, there is finite address space.

Comment: @Peter Thanks very much for your explanation. I guess the second scenario may explain my case.

Comment: @Raymond, could you please elaborate more? Why is the address space always finite even with infinite disk space? Thanks!

Comment: Let's take the example of an older, 32 bit machine. On such a machine, in general, the virtual address space is limited to no more than 2^32 bytes or about 4GB. Modern machines use 64 bit addressing so in theory can do 2^64 or 18 billion billion bytes. In reality, machines are limited to 40 to 48 bit addressing. 40 bits yields about 1000GB while 48 bits is 256 times bigger. In either case, disk space or disk quota or swapper space limits are what you are seeing. ps: I think your answer lies in reworking your program to use less memory. pps x^y means x to the power of y.

Answer (score 0):

Even with virtual memory the memory available is not unlimited.

Limit 1) Architectural limits. The processor and operating system will place some maximum virtual memory limit.

Limit 2) System Parameters. Many operating systems configure the maximum virtual memory size.

Limit 3) Process quotas. Many operating system have process quotas that limit the maximum virtual memory size.

Limit 4) System resources. Notably page file space.